# Are Maven 3 parallel builds stable

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am currently running maven parallel builds using maven 3.

```
mvn -T 2C clean install
```

can some one tell are these are stable or not.

Comment: This is an experimental feature, but it's pretty stable. I haven't come across any issues with it so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parallel build feature per se is pretty stable for me. Just watch out for the plugins that you are using because they need to be thread safe. You will receive a warning if the plugins are not thread safe yet.

Comment: thank you. Will there be any problem if the plugins are not thread safe. can I ignore those warnings..

Comment: The plugin developer needs to explicitly mention that the plugin is thread safe. Sometimes the plugin has been built with thread safeness in mind, but it has not been marked as thread safe yet. So it really depends on the plugin. My recommendation is to check every warning that you get.