# Is the Maven 3.x's parallel builds feature still experimental?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

The article that's closest to what can be called official on this topic is this:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3 which says the feature is experimental as of `v3.0`. The article is almost 2 years old too. Is it still experimental, though?

I see that my parallel builds are stable and correct as long as my project is not dealing with `thread-safe` plugins, but I have not seen any official word on this being a regular feature (my apologies if I missed anything of that sort, I did do an extensive search before this post) yet. I just wanted to be sure before I start using it in certain projects.

EDIT: I did read the question that was used to mark this as duplicate before adding this question, but my question was not about the stability itself (I confirmed it myself that it's stable anyway), rather about the official word from Maven that it is no longer experimental.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are Maven 3 parallel builds stable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589626/are-maven-3-parallel-builds-stable)

Comment: The article says that is has been experimental for Maven 3.0 but this a long time ago and we have Maven 3.0.5, 3.1.1, 3.2.5 and 3.3.1 apart from that I'm using this feature for a long time (more than a year in a production environment). You should use most recent Maven versions.

Comment: @khmarbaise, I use the latest version, but that doesn't mean it's automatically a regular feature, is it? Well, it could be, but I'm just looking for the official word from the `Maven` that this is a regular feature and not experimental anymore.

Comment: Are you using Maven 3.3.1? Apart from that: What do you like to have? Something on the Web sites? If you take a look into the JIRA you will find things related to parallel build (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3004). I don't know what you mean by `official`?

Comment: You should probably ask on the [Maven User mailing list](http://maven.apache.org/mail-lists.html). That is where you will have the best chance of getting an "official" answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it amounts to a support answer that would be better answered in Maven's specific channels. It is also not a question that asks about a specific programming issue that you are encountering. Related: [Why we're not customer support for {your favorite company}](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)